# Hide "action bar" in lollipop , API 21

Tags: java, android

For some reason, in API 21, the app crashes every time i use a theme of "no action bar".

I saw here in another question that i should add `this.getActionBar().hide();`, so i tried it with a several different themes but it's not working.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and what's the solution for that?

Comment: show `logcat` to see where it is crashing

Comment: you might be using support library for backward compatibility try getSupportActionBar() for a change if it doesnot work post logcat and some more relevant code

Comment: @IllegalArgument, what should be the theme in the manifest whan i use in getSupportActionBar().hide()?

Comment: Try `getActionBar().hide();` or `getSupportActionBar().hide();` instead of `this.getActionBar().hide();`

Comment: We are not god or magician! Post logcat output so that we can have better idea and can suggest you!

Comment: this is the error:     "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.amit.example1/com.example.amit.example1.OpeningActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference"

Comment: @kitsuneFox did you try my suggestion of using getSupportActionBar() I am almost 100% sure that it will solve your problem

Comment: @IllegalArgument, yes i did, but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting a NullPointerException on

```
    this.getActionBar().hide();
```

then that means your Activity has no Action Bar.

Hiding the system bars has been changed since KitKat. If you're trying to go into full screen mode you'll probably have to play around with the System UI Visibility flags. Check out the training pages here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Answer (score -1):

Modify your styles.xml using this theme

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If your Activity extends `ActionBarActivity` then

`getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Hope it helps!!!